# How to make a custom button that looks like a back button in NavigationBar? I mean the shape of the left side that is like an arrow

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

How to make a custom button that looks like a back button in NavigationBar? I mean the shape of the left side that is like an arrow.
In the sense how to set an image to back button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `UIButtonTypeCustom` style.
2. Set required image (with *shape of the left side that is like an arrow*) to background property.

Comment: sorry i need uibarbutton item,that is navigation back item.it doesnt have background property..normal button has it.Can u have any idea about this or code??

Comment: yea. At first create `UIButton`, after create `UIBarButtonItem` and initialize it with `- (id)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView;` Use button as customView

Comment: I donno object c,can  u explain briefly step by step.I am doing with monotouch.

Comment: `UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back-btn.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.width);
[button setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customItem;
[customItem release];`

Comment: var mybutton  = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
   mybutton.Frame=new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0,10,50,30);

Comment: UIImage imagebtn = UIImage.FromFile("Assets/cancel_active.png");
   mybutton.SetBackgroundImage(imagebtn,UIControlState.Normal);
   
   
   UIBarButtonItem backk=new UIBarButtonItem();
   
   backk.CustomView=mybutton;
   this.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = backk;

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(100,50,100,30);//set ur required frame
[backBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //Add back Like image
//use this button
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found is to use a stretchable button with a defined leftCapWidth to account for the pointy side of your button. That way if you ever need to change the label from "Back" "New Sales Customers" you don't need to re-export the background Image.

I even think they created a convenience extension for you:

```
var button = backButtonImage.StretchableButton(5, 0);
view.AddSubView(button);
```

[image: How to wire up a stretchable Image]

http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/08/stretchable-images-and-buttons/